# Codeigniter set_value Limitation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a form in Codeigniter with about 100 checkboxes. After validation, the set_value  works fine for the first checkboxes, but not for the rest. Is there any limitation for the amount of set_values?

```
<label>
<?php 
echo form_checkbox('indoor[]', '1', set_checkbox('indoor[]', 1)); ?>
Text 1
</label>
...
<label>
<?php 
echo form_checkbox('indoor[]', '100', set_checkbox('indoor[]', 100)); ?>
Text 100
</label>
```

Bests,
Yanick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `form_check_box` requires a boolean value which determines whether **checked** attribute is added to the generated input.

Therefore, try this

```
<label>
<?php 
echo form_checkbox('indoor[]', '1', in_array('1', set_value('indoor[]', []))); ?>
Text 1
</label>
...
<label>
<?php 
echo form_checkbox('indoor[]', '100', in_array('100', set_value('indoor[]', []))); ?>
Text 100
</label>
```

### Update

You can replace the second parameter of `set_value` with a persistent data for instance(depends on your implentattion). This will be returned by default if user hasn't submitted the form.